# How to convert pdf page into image in C# using Cyotek.GhostScript.PdfConversion

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, itext

i want to convert pdf page into image in C# using iTextSharp how can i do that

here is my method where i am getting all pages of pdf

```
    public void ExtractImage()
    {
          PdfReader pdf = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\Vipin\Desktop\slide.pdf");

          int pageNumber = pdf.NumberOfPages;
          for (int i = 1; i < pageNumber; i++)
          {
          }
   }
```

Comment: iTextSharp doesn't convert PDFs to images. You are probably mistaking iText for another tool such as JPedal.

Comment: then by what i can do this except iTextSharp by which i can convert pdf to Image @BrunoLowagie

Comment: or can i get the html of page using iTextSharp @BrunoLowagie

Comment: There is no such thing as "HTML" in a PDF page.

Comment: Why title says "Coytek.Ghostscript...".. and questions only mentions iTextSharp?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cyotek Ghostscript to do that. We first split our PDF files up into single pages.
We use this:

```
using Cyotek.GhostScript.PdfConversion;

private Bitmap PdfToBitmap(String path)
{
    Pdf2Image pdfimage = new Pdf2Image();
    pdfimage.Settings.Dpi = 300;
    pdfimage.PdfFileName = path;
    Bitmap bitmap = pdfimage.GetImage();
    return bitmap;
}
```

http://www.cyotek.com/downloads/view/Cyotek.GhostScript.PdfConversion.zip/